# Error with Nested Excel IF formula

Tags: excel

```
=IF(ISBLANK(BLANK(CG3),"",(IF((LEFT(CG,2)="/m"),"mcat||"&CG3,"icat||"&CG3)))
```

I am getting a #NAME? error on the above formula.

CG3 contains either `/mcat/...` OR `/icat/...` currently.  I need to add the prefix `"mcat||" or "icat||"` depending on the text currently there.  Also, if CG3 is blank I want it to remain blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 Issues:

- Missing parenthesis in the ISBLANK function. (On second thoughts, this looks like a copy/paste issue.)
- Missing cell number in the LEFT function.

Should be:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(CG3),"",IF(LEFT(CG3,2)="/m","mcat||"&CG3,"icat||"&CG3))
```

Comment: Should mention that BLANK() is not a valid Excel function. Its use is one source of the #NAME? error.

Comment: @chuff That's what lead me to believe it was a copy/paste error. The fact that the parentheses did not match would cause a popup warning.

Comment: You are correct, I pasted wrong - BLANK was a typo.  I also never caught the missing row number in my LEFT argument.  THANKS! (I can't believe I missed that!)